# Sankey diagram of HIGHCHARTS, highchart-node duplicate line (left line and right line)

Tags: highcharts, sankey-diagram

How to show 1 line of node in sankey diagram highcharts?
in ['Portugal', 'Portugal', 2], I want to show only one line (right) and set height of only this line smaller.
Please help me!
link: [https://jsfiddle.net/nd28eymv/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rd37t.png)

[image]

In my picture, I want to hide (1) and only show (2), then at (2), I want to set the height of this

[image]

Comment: I am afraid that it is hard to understand your requirement from the description. Could you share a picture of the output that you want to achieve?

Comment: @SebastianWędzel I just added a description, can you help me?

Comment: But are you able to share a finished result that you want to achieve? The requirements from your images break the sankey series functionality.

Comment: @SebastianWędzel https://i.stack.imgur.com/OIP0P.png
This is my finished result

Comment: I am afraid that it is impossible without customizing the core code. The sankey chart has been created to represent a flow between two nodes.

Comment: I'm so saddd, i just want to customize UI of "FROM node TO self that node". It's so difficult for me. Is it really out of the way?

Comment: Yes, it is. There is no API options to achieve it - this kind of option wasn't predicted and it disturbs the sankey chart.